# Why are toilet door lock indicators this way around?

Tags: gui-design

Why do the colors on a toilet door display the opposite to the principles used in engineering UI's such as power stations?

For example, a screen full of red dots is a good thing as the color shows the current state of the system. Red = alarm not active = no errors. Green = alarm active = errors.

Following this logic on a toilet door they would be Green = active = do not enter. Red = not active = enter.

Yet this appears to be the opposite. Red = active/occupied = do not enter. Green = not active/occupied = do enter.

[image]

The only thing I can think of is they use coloration similar to a traffic light system. Green = go. Red = stop.

Does anyone have any insight as to why they are opposite yet both are showing the current state of the system?

Comment: _If_ they use red in power stations, it will almost certainly be as a _warning that power is applied_, not that there is no alarm. In both cases, red is expressing warning/caution.

Comment: I got this information about power station warnings from my wifes grandad who worked in nuclear power stations as a senior engineer and manager for over 30 years but things may have changed since. This does makes sense.

Comment: It works like a traffic light, not a system status. Green = you're all clear, go ahead. Red = stop, you need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

The indication meaning is quite the same from a perspective of the one who is going to apply an action to the subject that sate is displayed.

In the aforementioned cases a green indication means a valid state for continuing a regular  application (or use) of a subject. A subject can be a plant, a road, a restroom, etc.